# Set column type as text in DataTable export

Tags: php, excel, datatable, export

I need to set a column as type text in Excel export from DataTable. All columns are in 'General' mode, so if data from a cell is datelike (2020-11-01 e.g.), Excel trats it like a date and I need it to be a string. This is my code regarding the table.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        var groupColumn = 0;
        var table = $('#Table1').DataTable( {
            "paging":   true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "info":     false,

            language: {
                search: "_INPUT_",
                searchPlaceholder: "Filtra risultati",
            },
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Esporta dati',
                    title: '',
                    header: true,
                    extend: 'excel',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    pageSize: 'LEGAL'
                },
            ],
            select: true,

        } );
    } );
</script>
```

There is a way to force DataTable to set my third column as TEXT?

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
// (...)
buttons: [
  {
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    title: "Your Report Name",
    exportOptions: {
        columns: ':visible',
    },
    customize: function (xlsx, data) {
        var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
        $('row c[r^="C"]', sheet).attr('s', '0');
    }
},
```

But note that will set cell type to GENERAL, not TEXT.

This is searching for all cells (row c) in third column (r^="C") and setting the style (s attribute) to 0 (the datatables built-in style for GENERAL content).

**If you are reading this answer trying to do the opposite, formating numbers as numbers and dates as dates, the following code did the trick for me:**

```
// (...)
buttons: [
  {
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    title: "Your Report Name",
    exportOptions: {
        columns: ':visible',
        format: {
            body: function (data, row, column, node) {
                if (column === 3) { // if you have a number in 4th column
                    return parseFloat(data);
                } else if (column === 2) { // if you have a date in 3rd column
                    var dateVal = Date.parse(data); // yyyy-MM-dd
                    var ticks = Math.round(25569 + (dateVal / (86400 * 1000)));
                    return ticks;
                } else {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    customize: function (xlsx, data) {
        var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
        var styles = xlsx.xl['styles.xml'];
        var dateStyle = "<xf numFmtId='14' fontId='0' fillId='0' borderId='0' applyFont='1' applyFill='1' applyBorder='1' xfId='0' applyNumberFormat='1' />";

        styles.childNodes[0].childNodes[5].innerHTML += dateStyle;

        $('row c[r^="D"][s=65]', sheet).attr('s', '64');

        $('row c[r^="C"][s=65]', sheet).attr('s', '67');
    }
},
```